# Writing an .htaccess file properly

Tags: .htaccess, dns

I have the following code in my .htaccess file; it was given to me in an attempt to redirect users from one website to another, but while masking the URL such that the original domain was kept:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^Shmoo.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.Shmoo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://wubbins.com/humnewum/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^Shmoo.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.Shmoo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://wubbins.com/humnewum/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I cannot use the generic Web forwarding, redirect, or Alias tools on one.com as these seem to use iFrames and therefore the destination site does not present properly on mobile devices.

This code seems to work, for the most part (as in no iFrame) but the URL is not masked, it is displayed as the destination 'www.wubbins.com/humnewum' not the origin 'www.Shmoo.com'

Complete noob so any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are these domains pointing to different servers?

Comment: Hi Mr White, yes, the first domain (shmoo) is on server A and the second domain (wubbins) is on server B - sadly I do not know the IP of server B